# recursive defined set

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $ S $ be a recursively defined set : \begin{align} 6 \in S\\ n \in S \rightarrow 4n+2 \in S , \\ n \in S \rightarrow n^{2} \in S  \end{align}. **Prove that every element of** $ S $ **has a last digit 6 (end with 6) in their decimal expansion** i.e; $ \ x \in \ S \ \ implies \ \ x \equiv 6 \ (mod \ 10 ) \ $. $$ $$ Given $ \ \ \ 6 \ \  \in S \  , \ \ 4n+2 \in S \ , \ \ n^{2} \in S $. From these we have to construct a formula f(n) so that $ f(n) \equiv 6 \ (mod \ 10) $. **Please help me doing this.**

Comment: You don't need to. Just do a proper induction. That is, if $n = 10m + 6$, what is $4n+2$? And so on.

Comment: Supposing if $n < 6$ then $n \not\in S$, what is true about $4n+2$ and $n^2$ if $n = 6 \mod 10$?

Comment: There is no sequence or indexing to the set-- there is no indication that you start with n = 6 or in what order you do it in.  So it's pretty vague how you can define f(n).  And it seem unnescessary.  but I suppose we could define Let $f_0(k)=4k+2;f_1(k)=k^2$ and if ${b_i}$ be is the binary digits of $n$ then $f(-1) = 6$ and for $n\ge 0$, $f(n) = f_{b_k}(f_{b_{k-1}}(f_{b_{k-2}}(...... f_{b_1}(f_{b_0}(6))))).....)$.  Kind of ... well.....

Comment: From these we have to construct a formula f(n) so that f(n)≡6 (mod 10).... Well, it doesn't say *anything* that $f(N) = S$.  You could ineffectively do $f(n) = 6^{n}$ .... which has nothing to do with the problem but it is a simple solution.  Heck $f(n) = 6$ is even simpler.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty unclear how the formula $f(n)$ is supposed to relate to the rest of the problem. I suppose $f(n)$ could be a relation such that given $n$ it produces two values: $4n+2$ and $n^2$. $f(n)$ wouldn't be a function in this case, but the OP doesn't say function, it says formula. One formula would be $f(n) = (\pm(4n+2-n^2)\mp(4n+2+n^2))/2$.

Answer (score 1):

All elements in $S$ are natural numbers. Suppose that the statement is not correct, then let us consider the smallest element $x \in S$ which doesn't have $6$ as its last digit.

If $x$ is a square of some number from $S$, then it means that there exists $n \in S$ such that $n^2 = x$. But $n < x$, so $n$ has $6$ as a last digit $\Rightarrow$ so does $x = n^2$.

If $x$ was got as $x = 4n+2$ for some $n \in S$, then, again, $n < x$, so $n$ has $6$ as a last digit $\Rightarrow$ so does $x = 4n+2$.

So we have a contradiction, which means that our initial assumption that such $x$ exists was false.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it is by induction:

If $n \equiv 6 \mod 10$ then $n^2 \equiv 36 \equiv 6 \mod 10$ and $4n +2 \equiv 4*6 + 2 \equiv 26 \equiv 6 \mod 10$.

That's it.

.....

But I didn't define $f(n)$.  I don't think you need to but... for $n \in \mathbb N$ (doesn't include zero).

Let $f(1) = 6$. $f(1) \equiv 6 \mod 10$.

If $n$ is even $f(n) = 4f(\frac n2)+ 2$ (if $f(\frac n2) \equiv 6 \mod 10$ then $f(n) \equiv 4*6 + 2\equiv 6 \mod 10$.)

If $n$ is odd but $n > 1$ then $f(n) = (f(\frac{n-1}2))^2$ (if $f(\frac{n=1}2)\equiv 6 \mod 10$ then $f(n)\equiv 6^2 \equiv 6 \mod 10$.)

....hmmm. using this definition I'm a little curious to find the first $f(n) = f(m); n \ne m$.  .... but not curious enough to do it...